# Retrieve a given string by Ajax - struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I want to retrieve a data sent by struts 2 to JSP page. I use ajax to retrieve this data.
My goal is to retrieve this data and to display it as a console message in my JSP.
How can i do it please?

Java code:

```
@Action(value = "enableFlux", results = { @Result(name= "success",type = TYPE_JSON), @Result(name="error", type = "messageError") })
public String enableFlux() {
  //another code
  if (trameRetour == null) {
    String messageError = "Problème d'abonnement !";
    return error;
  }
  else {
    return success;
  }
}
```

My JSP :

```
function enableFlux(image,idAbonnement) {

  if(confirm("Confirmez-vous l\'activation du flux "+idAbonnement)==true){
    $.ajax({
      type : "post",
      url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/flux/enableFlux.action',
      data : "idAbonnement="+idAbonnement,
      contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      success : function(data, status, request) {
        image.src = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/styles/img/boutontrue.png";
        $("#span"+data.abonnement.id).addClass("spanLabeltrue");
        $("#span"+data.abonnement.id).removeClass("spanLabelfalse");
      },
      error : function(data, status, request){
        alert ("Problème d'abonnement à Canal Train");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your error ?!

Comment: I don make the code to retrieve `messageError` in my JSP because i don't how i do it and this is my question

Comment: I think you have this miss understanding. The `error` function in the `javascript ajax` calls does not mean that you return `error` from the server. Let me say this way... When the ajax calls ends the `success function in javascript` is called. So you need to paras the `data` and find if it is `success` or `error message` . The `ajax error function` is only trigered when the `ajax` call ends with error for example `time out`

Comment: Dear @RomanC, can you please review the question, I doubt if this is a duplicate, thanks!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi I have done this question.

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi yes in the begining, i misunderstund..Now i'm trying to find a solution about how i can retrieve a data type `String` in my JSP using Ajax, sent by Struts